# Div Horizontal Scrollbar - Child div background doesn't get full width when hovering

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create a list of items using divs with a horizontal scrollbar.

I also need to have a hover effect applying a background color on each item of my list.

Each item must occupy 100% of each line when hovered.

My container should have an absolute position, I can't modify it.

When I have a small list without scrollbar my CSS is working well. However, when I have a long item the hover effect doesn't apply the background on the text that overflows. It is applied only on the first 400px inherited from the container.

Following the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='item'> LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM </div>
    <div class='item'>LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM LONG ITEM </div>
 </div>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 400px; 
  background: gray; 
}
.wrapper{
  width: 100%; 
  overflow: auto;
}
.item {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
}
.item:hover{
  background: #4178be;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

**DEMO**:
https://jsfiddle.net/gj5uwz30/4/

Does anybody has any idea about how should I solve this problem?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `.item` an `inline-block` and replace `width: 100%;` with `min-width: 100%;`

```
 .item {
      display: inline-block;
      min-width: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap;
      padding: 5px;
      height: 20px;
    }
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o87xp5jd/1/

ADDITION:

Second solution after comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o87xp5jd/2/

This solution makes the `.wrapper` being full width of the items and scrolled inside the `.container`

Comment: HI Johannes, Thank you but each item must be treated as an item list, it means that each item must occupy 100% of the line when hovered.

Comment: I added another version which does that

Answer (score 0):

The way you did it is wrong, you should make a container with display table,  max-width 400px and overflow auto.
Then add items inside with width% and display block and it will correctly work